# Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange (including GIS Stack Exchange)

Tags: support, stack-exchange

An **unofficial** list of new features and various changes to Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network including GIS Stack Exchange.

Updates are rolling and are now implemented on a daily basis.

Example:

**August 2013**

- 2013-08-12?: It is possible to see own deleted answers and questions.
  `http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<userID>` and
  `http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<userID>`.
  Linked from "answers" and "questions" tag in profile page.
- 2013-08-05: Closing a question will no longer incur an automatic
  Community downvote.
- 2013-08-01: (estimated date only, no source on Meta) Links are now
  being parsed when flagging as Other and writing custom text.
  Supported link format is the usual markdown link text.

**Full List and see the updates in Chronological order:**

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an answer here is not expected. Users interested in following feature changes in Stack Exchange can read (and favorite/bookmark) the full post from Meta Stack Exchange.